# useContext() returns undefined values -

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-context

I have a context file and state file for Products. when I try to use that context in products component it is returning undefined values

**productContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const ProductContext = createContext();

export default ProductContext;
```

**ProductState.js**

```
import ProductContext from './productContext';
import { useState } from 'react';

const ProductState = (props) => {
  const productsInitial = [
    {
      "_id": "63a4cc857f40d0063116be5f",
      "user": "63a4cbfd7f40d0063116be5d",
      "title": "Cassava",
      "description": "On-demand sand castle construction expertise.",
      "imgURL": "null",
      "price": "30",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "63a4ccad7f40d0063116be69",
      "user": "63a4cbfd7f40d0063116be5d",
      "title": "Soyabeans",
      "description": "On-demand sand castle construction expertise.",
      "imgURL": "null",
      "price": "30",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(productsInitial);
  // console.log(products);

  return (
    <>

      <ProductContext.Provider value={{ products, setProducts }}>
        {props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
}


export default ProductState;
```

**ProductComponent.js** (react component)

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import ProductContext from '../context/products/productContext';
import ProductItems from './ProductItems';

console.log(ProductContext);
const ProductComponent = () => {
    const context = useContext(ProductContext);
    const { products, setProducts } = context;
    return (
        <>
            <div className="col-lg-4 ">
                {products.map((product) => {
                    return <ProductItems product={products} />
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductComponent;
```

the line

```
const context = useContext(ProductContext);
```

in Products.js Component is returning undefined value because ProductContext is returning undefined

Comment: Where do you use `ProductState` component?

Comment: @kennarddh I am have not used the ProductState component explicitly anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Component that use the context must be wrapped using `ProductState` component

If you don't know where to add `ProductState` you can add in your entry point file.

```
root.render((
  <ProductState>
    <App />
  </ProductState>
))
```

You can simplify the object destructuring

```js
const { products, setProducts } = useContext(ProductContext);
```